# WKHTMLTOPDF with Patched QT Ubuntu 14.04 Errors during compiling

Tags: qt, ubuntu, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to compile the wkhtmltopdf with patched qt using these instructions and when i get to the make && make install it gives me an error has anyone else done this on Ubuntu 14.04? I can't figure out what to do from here.

these are the instructions i am following i know they are not for 14.04 but i hoped they would have worked https://gist.github.com/Zauberfisch/8773593

This is the error i get:

> cd src/lib/ && make -f Makefile make[1]: Entering directory /temp/wkhtmltopdf/src/lib' rm -f libwkhtmltox.so.0.12.1 libwkhtmltox.so libwkhtmltox.so.0 libwkhtmltox.so.0.12 g++ -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/temp/wkqt/lib -shared -Wl,-soname,libwkhtmltox.so.0 -o libwkhtmltox.so.0.12.1 ../../build/loadsettings.o ../../build/multipageloader.o ../../build/tempfile.o ../../build/converter.o ../../build/websettings.o ../../build/reflect.o ../../build/utilities.o ../../build/pdfsettings.o ../../build/pdfconverter.o ../../build/outline.o ../../build/tocstylesheet.o ../../build/imagesettings.o ../../build/imageconverter.o ../../build/pdf_c_bindings.o ../../build/image_c_bindings.o ../../build/moc_multipageloader_p.o ../../build/moc_converter_p.o ../../build/moc_pdfconverter_p.o ../../build/moc_imageconverter_p.o ../../build/moc_pdf_c_bindings_p.o ../../build/moc_image_c_bindings_p.o ../../build/moc_converter.o ../../build/moc_multipageloader.o ../../build/moc_utilities.o ../../build/moc_pdfconverter.o ../../build/moc_imageconverter.o ../../build/qrc_wkhtmltopdf.o -L/temp/wkqt/lib -lQtWebKit -lQtSvg -L/temp/wkqt/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lQtXmlPatterns -lQtGui -lQtNetwork -lQtCore -lpthread /usr/bin/ld: ../../build/qrc_wkhtmltopdf.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC ../../build/qrc_wkhtmltopdf.o: error adding symbols: Bad value collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make[1]: *** [../../bin/libwkhtmltox.so.0.12.1] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory `/temp/wkhtmltopdf/src/lib' make: *** [sub-src-lib-make_default-ordered] Error 2

Comment: Are you mixing 32 and 64 bits?

Comment: I am not sure if i am or am not. Is there a way to know? which one i am doing? I can tell you i have deleted everything and started over just doing the steps in the link i provided that i used as instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded a binary from [their site](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) that already had the QT build and that fixed the issue for me. Thanks!

Comment: "their site"?  whose site did you download it from?  can you provide a link to the binary?

Comment: yea... a link would be nice.